# Deploy Django cms on Heruku

Tags: django, heroku, django-cms

I'm trying to deploy a Django CMS on Heruku.
I follow the instruction at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git - but when I run the last command this is the result:

```
(web1)users-imac:1web user$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 453, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (439/439), done.
Writing objects: 100% (453/453), 1.21 MiB | 105 KiB/s, done.
Total 453 (delta 30), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files

! Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:intense-oasis-8026.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:intense-oasis-8026.git'
```

So I guess something went wrong, not sure what.

Those my heroku login output:

```
 2013-07-07T14:20:41.610222+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by alex.garulli@gmail.com
 2013-07-07T14:20:41.623083+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by alex.garulli@gmail.com
 2013-07-07T14:21:18+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
 2013-07-07T14:21:21+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: no Cedar-supported app detected
 2013-07-07T14:22:25.296159+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app"    method=GET path=/ host=intense-oasis-8026.herokuapp.com fwd="86.161.229.49" dyno= connect=   service= status=502 bytes=
 2013-07-07T14:22:25.474698+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=intense-oasis-8026.herokuapp.com fwd="86.161.229.49" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
 2013-07-07T21:53:38.496649+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=intense-oasis-8026.herokuapp.com fwd="120.168.1.115" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
 2013-07-07T21:53:48.291460+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=intense-oasis-8026.herokuapp.com fwd="120.168.1.115" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
 2013-07-07T21:53:51.282218+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=intense-oasis-8026.herokuapp.com fwd="120.168.1.115" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
 2013-07-08T18:29:16+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
 2013-07-08T18:29:17+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: no Cedar-  supported app detected
```

ok my Procfile worked , with foreman start

```
20:30:16 web.1  | started with pid 13580
20:30:16 web.1  | /usr/local/foreman/bin/foreman-runner: line 41: exec: gunicorn: not  found
20:30:16 web.1  | exited with code 127 
20:30:16 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

But same results for  git push heroku master

**UPDATE**

I guess my git push heroku master worked ...or at least loaded a lot of stuff...but know I have in my page

> > Application Error
> >     An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again >>in a few moments.
> >
> > If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Not sure what to do....

**UPDATE**

sorry  but couldnt mange to push it on heroku

you can view all my code at https://bitbucket.org/agarulli/trydj/src

any ideas pls?

Comment: What is in your `requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure **gunicorn & dj-database-url** is in your requirements.txt file and add it to your settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'gunicorn',
    ...
)

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

And **choose one** & change of your Procfile like this:

```
web: gunicorn YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

(Change YOUR_PROJECT_NAME into your project name)

or

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

(If you don't want to use Gunicorn server).

Recreate a new repository and new cedar by run following commands using Virtualenv:

```
workon YOUR_PROJECT
pip freeze > requirements.txt
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit -am "YOUR COMMIT"
heroku create --stack cedar
git push heroku master
```

Syncing your database using this command:

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

Open your application:

```
heroku open
```

Comment: Yes if you want to use gunicorn otherwise just use `web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload` on your Procfile.

Btw, did you tried my answers?

Comment: Yep I have tried ...I think I m pushing the files on heroku but I still have Application error when I open it

Comment: while I push I can see this problem :Successfully installed Django PIL South cmsplugin-filer django-classy-tags django-cms django-filer django-mixins django-mptt django-polymorphic django-sekizai easy-thumbnails gunicorn html5lib six
       Cleaning up...
-----> Collecting static files
       Traceback (most recent call last):
       OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/static'
 !     Error running manage.py collectstatic. More info:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets - do you think it can cause the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Heroku cannot understand what kind of App this is or you do not have access to that git repo.

What you need to do is add your SSH key to your account in order for this to work, because this is probably the problem.

If this does not work, then try rebasing.

Could you give us more information regarding your configuration if you configured Heroku right? If you are new to git altogether, then I suggest that you learn how it works before you attempt this.

Also, make sure to send `requirements.txt` to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `requirements.txt` in your project root folder? Without it Heroku won't understand you want to install Python app.

Comment: I have that along with a procfile.txt

Comment: You need Procfile instead of procfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set up SSH key on your computer as describe this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys and then you can following this articles: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django to deploy Django on Heroku.

Can you share the output of `heroku logs` command?

Comment: I guess the problem is in Procfile. cos when I run  foreman start
gave me : ERROR: Procfile does not exist.
I put my Procfile. next to my requirement.txt (generated by pip freeze > requirements.txt) in the folder wher manage.py is

Comment: and this my Procfile. content:web: gunicorn ftlom.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT